# Authoritative position of duplicate HTTP GET query keys

Tags: http, uri

I am having trouble on finding authoritative information about the behavior with HTTP GET query string duplicate fields, like

```
http://example.com/page?field=foo&field=bar
```

and in particular if the order is kept or not. Most web-oriented languages produce an array containing both foo and bar associated to a key "field", but I would like to know if authoritative statement exist (e.g. on a RFC) about this point. [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) has a section `3.4. Query`, which refers to key=value pairs, but nothing is said on how to interpret order and duplicate fields and so on. This makes sense, since it's backend dependent, and not in the scope of that RFC...

Although a de-facto standard exists, I'd like to see an authoritative source for it, just out of curiosity.

Comment: Been wondering about that, too. The other thing is the spec about merging the parameters from the query string with those in the POST body.

Comment: Over at the code ranch, people say there is no order guarantee. But that thread is old and no one backs it up in any way: http://www.coderanch.com/t/357197/Servlets/java/getParameterValues-order

Comment: In addition to the server keeping the order of the query string, there is also the question about the browser sending them in DOM (or some other fixed) order.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The situation seems to have changed since this question was asked and the accepted answer was written 12 years ago. I believe we now have an authoritative source: The WHATWG URL Standard describes the process of extracting and parsing a query string in detail in section 6.2 (https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-urlsearchparams) and section 5.1 on x-www-form-urlencoded parsing (https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlencoded-parsing). The parsing output is "an initially empty list of name-value tuples where both name and value hold a string", where a list is defined as a finite **ordered** sequence, and the key-value pairs are added to this list in the order they appear in the URL. At first there is no mention of repeated keys, but some methods on the URLSearchParams class in section 6.2 (https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-urlsearchparams) set clear expectations on ordering: "The `getAll(name)` method steps are to return the values of all name-value pairs whose name is name... **in list order**"; The `sort()` method specifies that "**The relative order between name-value pairs with equal names must be preserved.**" (Emphasis mine). Examining the Github issue referenced in the commit where the sort method was added, we see that the original proposal was to sort on values where keys were identical, but this was changed: "The reason for the default sort not affecting the value order is that **ordering of the values can be significant**. We should not assume that it's ok to move the order of the values around." (https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/26#issuecomment-271600764)

Answer (score 132):

There *is no spec* on this. You may do what you like.

Typical approaches include: first-given, last-given, array-of-all, string-join-with-comma-of-all.

Suppose the raw request is:

```
GET /blog/posts?tag=ruby&tag=rails HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Then there are various options for what `request.query['tag']` should yield, depending on the language or the framework:

```
request.query['tag'] => 'ruby'
request.query['tag'] => 'rails'
request.query['tag'] => ['ruby', 'rails']
request.query['tag'] => 'ruby,rails'
```

Comment: More to the point of the question, there is also the option of ['rails', 'ruby'] (different order).

Comment: .NET will give you as an array (I have not cared about the order when I tested that), PHP will give you always the last and Java (at least the system I worked with based on Java) always the first value.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked/8972025#8972025

Comment: This is based on an attack called HTTP Parameter Pollution and has been analyzed by OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/images/b/ba/AppsecEU09_CarettoniDiPaola_v0.8.pdf At page 9 you'll find a list of 20 systems and a description how they handle this issue.

Comment: @SimonSimCity in addition to that, PHP will actually create an array if you append square brackets with an optional index to the parameter name.

Comment: @SimonSimCity, Java will return the first value or the array of values depending on whether you call getParameter or getParameterValues.

Comment: how can i get it as an array in `js`?

Answer (score 15):

I can confirm that for PHP (at least in version 4.4.4 and newer) it works like this:

```
GET /blog/posts?tag=ruby&tag=rails HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

results in:

```
request.query['tag'] => 'rails'
```

But

```
GET /blog/posts?tag[]=ruby&tag[]=rails HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

results in:

```
request.query['tag'] => ['ruby', 'rails']
```

This behavior is the same for GET and POST data.

Comment: The `[]` suffix seems like really strange behaviour, but if you try to send an Array as an argument via jQuery's `.ajax()`, then it'll automatically add them for you in the same way. It looks like this is to the benefit of PHP users.

Comment: @IanClark It's intuitive to PHP coders - in plain PHP, `$foo[] = 1` appends to an array.  Django (Python) also does the same thing.

Comment: Can verify on Apache Tomcat it returns comma-concatenated strings.

Answer (score 9):

yfeldblum's answer is perfect.

Just a note about a fifth behavior I noticed recently: on **Windows Phone**, opening an application with an uri with a duplicate query key will result in NavigationFailed with:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key had already been added.

The culprit is `System.Windows.Navigation.UriParsingHelper.InternalUriParseQueryStringToDictionary(Uri uri, Boolean decodeResults)`.

So the system won't even let you handle it the way you want, it will forbid it. You are left with the only solution to choose your own format (CSV, JSON, XML, ...) and uri-escape-it.

Comment: That seems like an internal bug of that function, rather than a design choice. The probably function doesn't check for duplicate keys in the Dictionary it's creating. Dictionaries, of course, require unique keys.

Comment: So the *client browser* -- not the server -- is throwing an error in this situation? It does seem like a bug. I wonder if this bug still exists today?

Comment: @JonSchneider Yes, the client is throwing `NavigationFailed` for such URI. But, forgive me, I dropped Windows (Phone) development a month after this post and I moved to macOS (iOS), so I can't help anymore to track this issue nowadays.

Answer (score 6):

Most (all?) of the frameworks offer no guarantees, so assume they will be returned in random order.

Always take the safest approach.

For example, java HttpServlet interface:
[ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29)

Even the **getParameterMap** method leaves out any mention about parameter order (the order of a java.util.Map iterator cannot be relied on either.)

Comment: "offer no guarantees" or perhaps severely under-documented sprinkled with a bit of cowboy coding?

Answer (score 4):

Typically, duplicate parameter values like

```
http://example.com/page?field=foo&field=bar
```

result in a single queryString parameter that is an array:

```
field[0]=='foo'
field[1]=='bar'
```

I've seen this behavior in ASP, ASP.NET and PHP4.

Comment: exactly, this is the de-facto standard, but as far as I see there's no authoritative decision on it. Since I don't believe this is the case, I am just inept to find it.

Comment: Yes, probably everyone has seen that behaviour. The question was if that is actually specified somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The `?array[]=value1&array[]=value2` approach is certainly a very popular one.

- supported by most Javascript frameworks
- supported by Java Spring
- supported by PHP