# Parse NSURL path and query on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurl

Are there any standard objects or functions to parse an NSURL's components?  Clearly I could write one, but why re-invent the wheel?

`[NSURL path]` will return an `NSString` like `"argX=x&argY=y&argZ=z"`
What I would rather get back is a dictionary populated with `{@"argX" => @"x", @"argY" => @"y", @"argZ" = @"z"}`

For the path, which returns a string like "/partA/partB/partC", I would rather get an array with the structure `{[0] => @"partA", [1] => @"partB", [2] => @"partC"}`

I realize this is a pretty specific ask, but it seems like something a lot of people would want.

This is for iOS!  Apparently NSURL has different functions on macOS.

Comment: Good question. Do you mean: If the URL is "/partA/partB/partC", you want "0 => partA, 1=> partB, 2=>partC". If the URL is "/foo?partA=A&partB=B" you want "partA => A, partB => B". What if the URL is "/partA/partB/partC?foo=bar&ooga=booga"? In one example, the important information needed to identify the entity in question is being passed in a query string... in the other example, the identifying information is passed rest-style in the path itself.

Comment: I mean I want to parse the path and the query separately.  It should not be one function that combines those two tasks.  See the code I posted below for clarification.  If someone answers with an existing implementation, I'll be happy to still accept that.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that this is a perfectly valid query string: "x=1&x=0&x=foo", so an NSDictionary might not be the best representation (unless you're using arrays as the values).

Comment: @n8gray - You're right, my answer below doesn't deal with duplicate values.  I would avoid duplicate values like the plague in any real-world scenarios though, because many servers (PHP servers for example) will end up with only one value for x... x=>"foo", just like my script.  PHP *will* however, build an array out of "x[]=1&x[]=foo", which my answer will not do.  It should be a trivial exercise to expand my example to build arrays if the left hand parameter name ends in "[]" though, so I'll leave that for anyone who needs it to add.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to look at `pathComponents` which returns an array of the components of the URL. Get more information [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/pathComponents).

Comment: I don't believe this is available on the iphone version of the SDK.  I should have clarified that I'm working on iphone OS.

Comment: [NSString pathComponents] is available in both the Cocoa and Cocoa Touch APIs. On the iPhone, you can imitate OS X 10.6's [NSURL pathComponents] with [[NSURL path] pathComponents].

Comment: Ah perfect, that's what I was looking for, for the path portion at least!

Comment: Apple docs for [NSString pathComponents] state: "Note that this method only works with file paths (not, for example, string representations of URLs)."

Comment: @JasonMoore that's why you pass it the output of `-path` rather than the raw URL string

Comment: @MikeAbdullah: Ah, ok. For anyone else stumbling on this 3-year old question: As of iOS4 you no longer need to convert the URL to a string and can just use: -[NSURL pathComponents] directly.

Comment: pathComponents work great for RFC 1808 urls,  However if you are parsing a mailto it will return nil.

Answer (score 12):

Alright, I got antsy and wrote a solution for extending NSString through Categories.  I haven't tested this yet, but if you want to use it, go for it.

```
@interface NSString (ParseCategory)
- (NSMutableDictionary *)explodeToDictionaryInnerGlue:(NSString *)innerGlue outterGlue:(NSString *)outterGlue;
@end

@implementation NSString (ParseCategory)

- (NSMutableDictionary *)explodeToDictionaryInnerGlue:(NSString *)innerGlue outterGlue:(NSString *)outterGlue {
    // Explode based on outter glue
    NSArray *firstExplode = [self componentsSeparatedByString:outterGlue];
    NSArray *secondExplode;

    // Explode based on inner glue
    NSInteger count = [firstExplode count];
    NSMutableDictionary *returnDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:count];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        secondExplode = [(NSString *)[firstExplode objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:innerGlue];
        if ([secondExplode count] == 2) {
            [returnDictionary setObject:[secondExplode objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[secondExplode objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }

    return returnDictionary;
}

@end
```

It's called like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parsedQuery = [[myNSURL query] explodeToDictionaryInnerGlue:@"=" outterGlue=@"&"]
```

For parsing the path portion of the NSURL (ie @"/partA/partB/partC"), just call this:

```
NSArray *parsedPath = [[nyNSURL path] componentsSeperatedByString:@"/"];
```

Be aware that parsedPath[0] will be an empty string because of the leading /!

**EDIT** - Here is a Category extension to NSURL for your usage pleasure.  It strips the initial "/" so you don't have an empty 0 index.

```
@implementation NSURL (ParseCategory)

- (NSArray *)pathArray {
    // Create a character set for the slash character
    NSRange slashRange;
    slashRange.location = (unsigned int)'/';
    slashRange.length = 1;
    NSCharacterSet *slashSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:slashRange];

    // Get path with leading (and trailing) slashes removed
    NSString *path = [[self path] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:slashSet];

    return [path componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:slashSet];
}

- (NSDictionary *)queryDictionary {
    NSDictionary *returnDictionary = [[[[self query] explodeToDictionaryInnerGlue:@"=" outterGlue:@"&"] copy] autorelease];
    return returnDictionary;
}

@end
```

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this... that'll teach me to share code I guess?  I wouldn't really mind if you'd left a comment, but I'll just assume you're a random troll.  Hi troll.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for me. Note that you may need to URL-decode your individual query string values as well. I am using the following code for this, first to take care of percent-escapes, then to replace "+" with space, which the first one unfortunately doesn't do:
[[value stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "]

Comment: Very welcome.  And yes, I left matters of encoding/decoding out of these functions.

Answer (score 11):

Sam Soffes created a well maintained Category for NSURL / NSDictionary. It can be found here: https://github.com/samsoffes/sstoolkit/

Answer (score 5):

Heres what i use to parse the query string

```
// Parse the individual parameters
// parameters = @"hello=world&foo=bar";
NSMutableDictionary *dictParameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray *arrParameters = [parameters componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
for (int i = 0; i < [arrParameters count]; i++) {
    NSArray *arrKeyValue = [[arrParameters objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    if ([arrKeyValue count] >= 2) {
        NSMutableString *strKey = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];
        [strKey setString:[[[arrKeyValue objectAtIndex:0] lowercaseString] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSMutableString *strValue   = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];
        [strValue setString:[[[arrKeyValue objectAtIndex:1]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        if (strKey.length > 0) [dictParameters setObject:strValue forKey:strKey];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Parameters: %@", dictParameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do decide to write one (*I'm not sure there are existing methods of getting the components you want*), you might want to use NSString's `componentsSeparatedByString`.

Answer (score 2):

Introduced in iOS 8 and OS X 10.10 is `NSURLQueryItem`, which can be used to build queries. From the docs on [NSURLQueryItem](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLQueryItem_Class/index.html):

> An NSURLQueryItem object represents a single name/value pair for an item in the query portion of a URL. You use query items with the queryItems property of an NSURLComponents object.

You can retrieve the query items from a URL by first creating `NSURLComponents`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com?q=ios&count=10"];
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url 
                                               resolvingAgainstBaseURL:YES];
for (NSURLQueryItem *item in components.queryItems) {
    NSLog(@"name: %@, value: %@", item.name, item.value);
}
// name: q, value: ios
// name: count, value: 10
```

Note that they return value for `-queryItems` is an array, not a dictionary. This is because the following is a valid URL. Note the two identical "keys", `foo`.

`http://google.com?foo=bar&foo=baz`

To create a URL via query items, use the designated initializer `queryItemWithName:value:` and then add them to `NSURLComponents` to generate an `NSURL`. For example:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://stackoverflow.com";
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:urlString];
NSURLQueryItem *search = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"q" value:@"ios"];
NSURLQueryItem *count = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"count" value:@"10"];
components.queryItems = @[ search, count ];
NSURL *url = components.URL; // http://stackoverflow.com?q=ios&count=10
```

Notice that the question mark and ampersand are automatically handled. Creating an `NSURL` from a dictionary of parameters is as simple as:

```
NSDictionary *queryDictionary = @{ @"q": @"ios", @"count": @"10" };
NSMutableArray *queryItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in queryDictionary) {
    NSURLQueryItem *item = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:key 
                                                       value:queryDictionary[key]]; 
    [queryItems addObject:item];
}
components.queryItems = queryItems;
```

I've also written a blog post with more details, [Building NSURLs with NSURLQueryItems](http://masilotti.com/nsurlqueryitems/).

Comment: Cool!  Just a note to devs--if you use duplicate GET parameters you're in for a world of hurt.  There is no defined spec for how to handle those, and different languages/platforms make up their own rules.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746507/authoritative-position-of-duplicate-http-get-query-keys