# How to parse url in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, url, nsurl

Is there a function which could parse url into protocol, domain(IP), port, uri, etc.?
Just like the parse_url() function in PHP.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967399/parse-nsurl-path-and-query-iphoneos 
it shows how to parse url in objective-c.

Answer (score 4):

See the documentation of `NSURL`, in particular [+[NSURL URLWithString:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:).