# How to exctract data from NSURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsurl

I have the following `NSSURL`:

```
myURL - myPlatform://sdk/functionName?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

How can I get the URL components?

```
NSString *myPlatform = [myURL...?
NSString *functionName = [myURL...?
NSString *key1 = [myURL...?
NSString *value1 = [myURL...?
NSString *key2 = [myURL...?
NSString *value2 = [myURL...?
```

I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url= [request URL];
    Log(@"url: %@", url);
    NSArray *components = [url pathComponents];  
    for (NSString *c in components)
        Log(@"URL component: %@", c);
}
```

And this in the log:
url:

> url: myPlatform://sdk/functionName?key1=value1&key2=value2
>
> component: /
>
> component: functionName

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967399/parse-nsurl-path-and-query-iphoneos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the documentation:

```
NSString *myPlatfrom = [myURL scheme];
NSString *sdk = [myURL host];
NSString *functionName = [[myURL path] substringFromIndex:1];
NSString *query = [myURL query];
for (NSString *arg in [query componentsSeparatedByString:"&"]) {
    NSArray argComponents = [arg componentsSeparatedByString:"="];
    NSString key = [argComponents[0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString value = [argComponents[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```