# Jersey: QueryParam name as an array

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm looking for a way to map the following query parameters to jersey:

```
?sort['property1']=asc
?sort['property2']=desc
```

Is there a way i can pick that up as a single query parameter? A parametrized param-name, so to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is strange because, even before being a hard question regarding jersey possibilities, this is something that follows no HTTP GET standard.

See interesting comments here : [Authoritative position of duplicate HTTP GET query keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1746507/709881)

I don't think you can reliably interpret a query argument like : sort['property1']