# safe character to separate multiple urls

Tags: url

I am preparing a special string, in which keys are values are concatenated like below:

```
username=foo&age=24&email=foo@bar.com&homepage=http://foo.com
```

- & is the separator for two key=value pairs
- value is url encoded

I have a scenario where there are multiple home pages for a user. 
I want to specify multiple urls for the homepage key

```
name=foo&age=24&email=foo@bar.com&homepage=url1<some_safe_url_separator_char>url2<some_safe_url_separator_char>url3
```

- We have no control/idea over what url1, url2, .. may contain?

What is a good choice of some_safe_url_separator_char?
In other words I am not looking for a safe character to be used IN a url, but a safe character to be used to SEPARATE two urls in a string

Comment: you can use a `JSON` to pass data.instead of making a bulky url

Comment: Could you not pass multiple homepage variables? `name=foo&age=24&email=foo@bar.com&homepage=url1&homepage=url2&homepage=url3` [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746507/authoritative-position-of-duplicate-http-get-query-keys)

Comment: @Ashes JSON is not a choice, that I can make. The format is fixed

Comment: @Trengot I cannot repeat the same key; the parser is not designed to parse repeated keys

Comment: Can the homepage URLs also contain a path/query/fragment?

Answer (score -1):

well you can use **URL re-writing** for this .

It will make a URL that will be safe as it will hide the name of parameters

For refrence you can use [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

URL rewriting will make a url seprated by `'/'` and its tough to be **decoded** by an external person.
you can follow links i'm posting

[URL rewriting for beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)