# How can I build a URL with query parameters containing multiple values for the same key in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsurl

I am using AFNetworking in my iOS app and for all the GET requests it makes, I build the url from a base URL and than add parameters using NSDictionary Key-Value pairs.

The problem is that I need same key for different values.

Here is an example of what I need the finally URL to look like -

http://example.com/.....&id=21212&id=21212&id=33232

It's not possible in NSDictionary to have different values in same keys. So I tried NSSet but did not work.

```
let productIDSet: Set = [prodIDArray]
let paramDict = NSMutableDictionary()
paramDict.setObject(productIDSet, forKey: "id")
```

Answer (score 191, accepted):

All you need is `URLComponents` (or NSURLComponents in Obj-C). The basic idea is to create a bunch of query items for your id's. Here's code you can paste into a playground:

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: "1"), URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: "2")]
var urlComps = URLComponents(string: "www.apple.com/help")!
urlComps.queryItems = queryItems
let result = urlComps.url!
print(result)
```

You should see an output of

> www.apple.com/help?id=1&id=2

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your answer. I tried looping through and add the value in a for loop as I have my IDs in an array but I am facing a lot of issues. Will you be able to please suggest how do I add values in loop ? Many thanks.

Comment: sure, just make sure you declare your array of `queryItems` as a `var` and then you can add new items in a loop @AbhishekDwivedi

Comment: Sorry @Daniel to bug you but this is what I am trying to do but not able to.  Not sure what the problem is :(

var queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem]()
        let urlComps = NSURLComponents(string: "www.apple.com/help")!
        for var i = 0 ; i < prodIDArray.count ; i++ {
            let queryitem = [NSURLQueryItem(name: "id", value: prodIDArray[i] as? String)]
            queryItems.append(queryitem)
        }
     
        urlComps.queryItems = queryitems

Comment: You don't need to create a query item array in the loop. Just remove the square brackets and you should be good @AbhishekDwivedi

Comment: My url is like below
https://www.abcd.com/json/trend/id/12/key/23456
How can i achieve this ? 
I am using alamofire 4.0

Comment: If anyone get this `Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context` error, use URLQueryItem instead of NSURLQueryItem

Answer (score 89):

### **Method 1**

It can add the **QueryItem** to your existing URL.

```
extension URL {

    func appending(_ queryItem: String, value: String?) -> URL {

        guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: absoluteString) else { return absoluteURL }

        // Create array of existing query items
        var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] = urlComponents.queryItems ??  []

        // Create query item
        let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: queryItem, value: value)

        // Append the new query item in the existing query items array
        queryItems.append(queryItem)

        // Append updated query items array in the url component object
        urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems

        // Returns the url from new url components
        return urlComponents.url!
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
var url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")!
let finalURL = url.appending("test", value: "123")
                  .appending("test2", value: nil)
```

### **Method 2**

In this method, the URL will be updated automatically.

```
extension URL {

    mutating func appendQueryItem(name: String, value: String?) {

        guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: absoluteString) else { return }

        // Create array of existing query items
        var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] = urlComponents.queryItems ??  []

        // Create query item
        let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: name, value: value)

        // Append the new query item in the existing query items array
        queryItems.append(queryItem)

        // Append updated query items array in the url component object
        urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems

        // Returns the url from new url components
        self = urlComponents.url!
    }
}

// How to use
var url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")!
url.appendQueryItem(name: "name", value: "bhuvan")
```

Answer (score 12):

```
func queryString(_ value: String, params: [String: String]) -> String? {    
    var components = URLComponents(string: value)
    components?.queryItems = params.map { element in URLQueryItem(name: element.key, value: element.value) }

    return components?.url?.absoluteString
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Update for iOS 16, Swift 5.7+**

There's a shorter way available to perform this:

```
var url = URL(string: "http://google.com/search")
url?.append(queryItems: [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "soccer")])
print(url) // http://www.google.com/search?q=soccer
```

Functional style and immutable object:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://google.com/search")?
            .appending(queryItems: [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "soccer")])

print(url) // http://www.google.com/search?q=soccer
```

Comment: In iOS 16 there is even the non mutating function `appending`, which *returns* an appended URL.

Answer (score 11):

An URL extension to append query items, similar to Bhuvan Bhatt idea, but with a different signature:

- it can detect failures (by returning `nil` instead of `self`), thus allowing custom handling of cases where the URL is not RFC 3986 compliant for instance.
- it allows nil values, by actually passing any query items as parameters.
- for performance, it allows passing multiple query items at a time.

```
extension URL {
    /// Returns a new URL by adding the query items, or nil if the URL doesn't support it.
    /// URL must conform to RFC 3986.
    func appending(_ queryItems: [URLQueryItem]) -> URL? {
        guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
            // URL is not conforming to RFC 3986 (maybe it is only conforming to RFC 1808, RFC 1738, and RFC 2732)
            return nil
        }
        // append the query items to the existing ones
        urlComponents.queryItems = (urlComponents.queryItems ?? []) + queryItems

        // return the url from new url components
        return urlComponents.url
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/...")!
let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: nil),
                  URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: "22"),
                  URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: "33")]
let newUrl = url.appending(queryItems)!
print(newUrl)
```

Output:

> https://example.com/...?id&id=22&id=33

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to allow same key multiple times in a url

Comment: @atulkhatri while the RFC 3986 **allows** it, I'm well aware that, for instance, [on Windows Phone 7/8, the Operating System won't even let you handle URLs with duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26341732/1033581). So I fully agree that it's not the best practice. Consequently its usage will depend on your API. This is [how I filter duplicate keys in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684308/1033581): with the code from it, you could add `queryItems.unique(for: \.name)` if you want.

Comment: I completely understand your intention but I feel being it a front-end code, the app does not know how the server is going to handle it. So in order to be on a safer side, I think it is best to not have such inconsistent query parameters.

Answer (score 5):

## 2019

```
private func tellServerSomething(_ d: String, _ s: String) {
    
    var c = URLComponents(string: "https://you.com/info")
    c?.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "description", value: d),
        URLQueryItem(name: "summary", value: s)
    ]
    guard let u = c?.url else { return print("url fail") }
    do {
        let r = try String(contentsOf: u)
        print("Server response \(r)")
    }
    catch { return print("comms fail") }
}
```

Percent-encoding and everything else is handled.

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift Forming URL with multiple params**

```
func rateConversionURL(with array: [String]) -> URL? {
            var components = URLComponents()
            components.scheme = "https"
            components.host = "example.com"
            components.path = "/hello/"
            components.queryItems = array.map { URLQueryItem(name: "value", value: $0)}

        return components.url
    }
```

Comment: very impressive !

Answer (score -4):

I guess u just have to do something like this:

```
let params = ["id" : [1, 2, 3, 4], ...];
```

which will be encoded into:
....id%5B%5D=1&id%5B%5D=2&id%5B%5D=3&id%5B%5D=4....

Comment: And If you are working with swift I sagest you to use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)