# Swift URLRequest to Parse Platform REST API (JSON) & Decode into Struct

Tags: ios, json, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to use specific capabilities not available in the available iOS SDK for Parse Platform (Server), but that I know are available with the REST API. Specifically to use a DISTINCT query.

Using the Parse Dashboard and REST API client app on my dev computer (Rested.app), I have verified the following query completes as expected:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: someAppID" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: someKey" \
-G \
--data-urlencode "distinct=TeeTime" \
http://somehost:1337/parse/aggregate/CompEntry
```

Which successfully returns data:

> {
> "results": [
> {
> "__type": "Date",
> "iso": "2020-08-29T07:00:00.000Z"
> },
> {
> "__type": "Date",
> "iso": "2020-08-29T07:09:00.000Z"
> }
> ] }

The original data is from, which has 3 rows, 2 of which share the same TeeTime:

[image: Parse Dashboard screenshot]

And a screenshot of the output from the Rested.app:

[image: Rested.app Output screenshot]

Now I am trying to convert this for my Swift / iOS project.

I am trying to move the downloaded data into a new struct to represent the object(s), using the Codable/Decodable approach and matching the JSON property names. The code I have so far is below (placed some comments inline too). The Struct definitions occur in separate .swift files, but so long as outside the main ViewController definition.

```
struct TeeTimeData: Codable {
    let results: [Results]
}

struct Results: Codable {
    let __type: String
    let iso: String // TODO: THIS SHOULD BE A DIFFERENT DATA TYPE - I HAVE PICKED HARDER DATA TYPE TO START WITH!
}
```

Then within the main ViewController struct:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func buttonGetTeeTimes(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if let url = URL(string: "http://somehost:1337/parse/aggregate/CompEntry") {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.addValue("someAppID", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
            request.addValue("someKey", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Master-Key")
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            let params = ["distinct": "TeeTime"] // TODO: THIS VAR IS NOT ACTUALLY BEING TIED TO THE REQUEST EITHER - 2nd PROBLEM...
            
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            let requestTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                
                if error != nil {
                    print("API Error: \(error)")
                }
                
                if let dataUnwrap = data {
                    // TODO: MOVE THIS INTO NEW CLASS (DataModel, etc)
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    
                    do {
                        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(TeeTimeData.self, from: dataUnwrap)
                        
                        print(decodedData)
                        
                    } catch {
                        print("Decode Error: \(error)")
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
            
            requestTask.resume()
            
        }
    }
}
```

And the console output is:

> Decode Error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "__type", intValue:
> nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
> "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue:
> 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key
> CodingKeys(stringValue: "__type", intValue: nil) ("__type").",
> underlyingError: nil))

My first guess is the 2 underscores, "__type", at the start of the property definition?

Comment: There is no key `__type` in your response JSON.

Comment: `print("Decode Error: \(error)")` => `print("Decode Error: \(error)"); print("With response: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")`might help.

Comment: The *dummy data* doesn't cause that error, so the real data must be different.

Comment: @gcharita - I thought the returned JSON at the top-level is called "results" that consists of an array of sub-items, each of which has 2 properties (__type and iso). Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Larme, I would like to convert the returned data into Swift struct's not string manipulation

Comment: No, that's for debugging proposes. To see you real data, and might see why it fails while it didn't on your tests.

Comment: @vadian - by "dummy data" I mean the actual data that is stored on my Parse Platform instance. But its dummy data to prove the app / code logic. There are 3 rows of data entered into this class (table), but 2 of them share the same TeeTime, therefore only 2 items are returned.

Comment: `"--data-urlencode "distinct=TeeTime"` Doesn't it means that it'd add `&distinct=TeeTime` to the URL? You aren't doing it in your code, no? So maybe that's why the response is different (and why you might want to show the returned data as String).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the same thing. the `curl` statement provided is copy/pasted from an "Export" button provided on the Parse Dashboard

Comment: @jingo_man no, if your response JSON is like your dummy one, your model is correct.

Comment: I tried the String() manipulation, which returns ALL 3 rows but includes all information from each row, not filtered as I need from the `distinct` filter/query, because in my case I also haven't been able to apply the "distinct=TeeTime" portion (which does not seem to be passed in as a parameter as suggested by @Larme, but with the '-G' curl flag)

Comment: You can construct the url with `QueryComponents`, manually just to test your parsing, you should be able to write the URL `"http://somehost:1337/parse/aggregate/CompEntry&distinct=TeeTime` instead.

Comment: If I try `&distinct=TeeTime` appended to the URL, in the Rested.app output, all I get is: `{
    "results": []
}`

Comment: I meant `?distinct=TeeTime`, sorry, typo. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlqueryitem (and related StackOverflow questions if needed) to build it with your parameters.

Comment: Yes, `?distinct=TeeTime` to the end of the URL string works! And explains the problem I was experiencing. Without this filter/query, it was returning a different JSON structure, so it wasn't decoding into my TeeTimeData struct format. It does so now: `Decoded data: TeeTimeData(results: [Parse_2.Results(__type: "Date", iso: "2020-08-29T07:00:00.000Z"), Parse_2.Results(__type: "Date", iso: "2020-08-29T07:09:00.000Z")])`. Many thanks, @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by @Larme in the comments to the opening post. Contributions from @gcharita that my syntax *should* have worked if it was the same structure as the other tests I was performing (it wasn't - see below).

The error was occurring because the results being returned was a different JSON structure because the `distinct=TeeTime` filter wasn't being applied. So it was returning a JSON object with all the rows of data from the class, not those specified in my TeeTimeData struct object.

Appending `?distinct=TeeTime` to the end of the URL string resolved the issue and returns:

> Decoded data: TeeTimeData(results: [Parse_2.Results(__type: "Date",
> iso: "2020-08-29T07:00:00.000Z"), Parse_2.Results(__type: "Date", iso:
> "2020-08-29T07:09:00.000Z")])

It also means I no longer require the `let params = ["distinct": "TeeTime"]` code as well.

Comment: Keep the params, just use `URLQueryItems`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060754/how-can-i-build-a-url-with-query-parameters-containing-multiple-values-for-the-s