# Convert CURL to Swift

Tags: json, swift, curl

I need to convert the following curl call of Microsoft Azure Cloud to Swift:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=zh-Hans&toScript=Latn" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <client-secret>" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -d "[{'Text':'Hello, what is your name?'}]"
```

I need to convert a JSON call of curl to Swift. The problem is I have no experience with JSON calls and don't know how to include headers, a body and parameters.
So I tried the following code:

```
let apiKey = "..."
let location = "..."

class AzureManager {
    
    static let shared = AzureManager()
    
    func makeRequest(json: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (String)->()) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate"),
              let payload = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json) else {
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")
        request.addValue(location, forHTTPHeaderField: "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
        request.addValue("NaiVVl3DEFG3jdE5DE1NFAA6EABC", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-ClientTraceId")
        request.httpBody = payload

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else { completion("Error::\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))"); return }
            guard let data = data else { completion("Error::Empty data"); return }
            
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]

            if let json = json,
               let choices = json["translations"] as? [String: Any],
               let str = choices["text"] as? String {
                completion (str)
            } else {
                completion("Error::nothing returned")
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
let jsonPayload = [
           "api-version": "3.0",
           "from": "en",
           "to": "it",
           "text": "Hello"
           ] as [String : Any]
   
AzureManager.shared.makeRequest(json: jsonPayload) { [weak self] (str) in
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
           print(str)
     }
}
```

Well, the errors I get are:

```
    Optional(["error": {
        code = 400074;
        message = "The body of the request is not valid JSON.";
    }])
```

And:

Error::nothing returned

Here are the Docs of Microsoft Azure Translator:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate

Comment: Don’t return hard coded error messages, specially when troubleshooting a bug! Change from `try?` to `try` and catch the error and print/return it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze your `cURL command`, let's make it more readable with breaking line. If you want to make it working as such in Terminal.app, just add `\` at the end of the line.

```
curl \
-X POST \ 
"https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=zh-Hans&toScript=Latn" \
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <client-secret>" \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \ 
-d "[{'Text':'Hello, what is your name?'}]"
```

`-H`: Set with `addValue(_,forHTTPHeaderField:)`
`-d`: Set it with `httpBody =`
The long URL, that's `request.url`

There are two main differences between the cURL command and the `URLRequest` you mode.

First, you did mix payload & URL settings.

`url` should be `"https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=zh-Hans&toScript=Latn"`, not `"https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate"`, you put `api-version`, `to`, `toScript` (that one is missing by the way) inside `httpBody`.
Put them into the URL instead. You can use `URLQueryItem` to format them correctly. See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060754/how-can-i-build-a-url-with-query-parameters-containing-multiple-values-for-the-s).

Now, once you fix that, there is a second issue:

`[{'Text':'Hello, what is your name?'}]`, I'll by pass the strange fact that it's using single quotes, but, here JSON is an array at top level, not a dictionary. Also, it's `Text`, not `text` (it might be case sensitive).

If you want to see what you are sending in httpBody, do not hesitate to do:

```
if let jsonStr = String(data: request.httpBody ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8) {
    print("Stringified httpBody: \(jsonStr)")
}
```

So fix your parameters until it matches the on in the working `cURL` command. As said, it's an array, not a dictionary.

Finally, avoid using `try?`, please do proper `do`/`try`/`catch` because if it fails, at least you need to know about it.
No need to use `.allowFragments` if you don't expect a JSON String at top level. Here you are expecting a Dictionary.
And I'd recommand to use `Codable` now in Swift 4+ instead of `JSONSerialization`.

Edit: Seeing the doc, as you mixed the parameters/query, keep in mind:
"Query Parameters", that's for `URLQueryItems` and it's in the URL.
Request Body: That's for the `httpBody`.