# Axios multiple values (comma separated) in a parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Expected query string:

```
http://fqdn/page?categoryID=1&categoryID=2
```

Axios get request:

```
fetchNumbers () {
  return axios.get(globalConfig.CATS_URL, {
    params: {
      ...(this.category ? { categoryId: this.category } : {})
    }
  })
    .then((resp) => {
      // console.log(resp)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

As you can see, it works perfectly with just 1 value for 1 parameter, but if i wanted to make multiple values - it doesn't work, i've tried to use an array:

```
...(this.category ? { categoryId: [1, 2] } : {})
```

But it returns this way:

```
http://fqdn/page?categoryID[]=1&categoryID[]=2
```

So it just not working. Had a look at this issue: [Passing an object with a parameter with multiple values as a query string in a GET using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102575/passing-an-object-with-a-parameter-with-multiple-values-as-a-query-string-in-a-g/42102889#42102889)

But can't figure out, how he solved this problem.

Comment: You should [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74709544/1314986).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Axios's [`paramsSerializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152383/6277151) to customize the serialization of parameters in the request.

Note that [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) serializes array data the way you're expecting:

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
searchParams.append('foo', 1);
searchParams.append('foo', 2);
console.log(searchParams.toString()); // foo=1&foo=2
```

So you could use that class in `paramsSerializer` as follows:

```
// my-axios.js
export default axios.create({
  paramsSerializer(params) {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    for (const key of Object.keys(params)) {
      const param = params[key];
      if (Array.isArray(param)) {
        for (const p of param) {
          searchParams.append(key, p);
        }
      } else {
        searchParams.append(key, param);
      }
    }
    return searchParams.toString();
  }
});

// Foo.vue
import axios from './my-axios.js';

export default {
  methods: {
    async send() {
      const { data } = await axios({
        url: '//httpbin.org/get',
        params: {
          categoryId: [1, 2, 3]
        }
      });

      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vyzwnqq6ll)

Comment: Thanks, what for is `async` / `await` here?

Comment: [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is an ES2017 feature.

Comment: If ES2017 is not available in your project, you can use the ES2016-equivalent code: `send() { axios(...).then(response => { const data = response.data; }); }`

Answer (score 4):

This is not an axios related issue. It depends on whether your backend service is able to understand query params in this fashion(seems to be framework dependent). From your question, I think it is not working when queryParams like following are sent

```
?categoryID[]=1&categoryID[]=2
```

and it expects

```
?categoryID = 1,2
```

What you can do is transform array to such string before passing it to params in axios. Update the following piece in your code and it should solve your problem.

```
...(this.category ? { categoryId: this.category.join(',') } : {})
```

Take a look at following thread

[How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

Comment: I assume `this.category` should be an array, right>

Comment: @AlexanderKim yes it is an array as per your question. categoryId: [1, 2]

Comment: I don't quite understand, i showed in my code above `...(this.category ? { categoryId: [1, 2] } : {})` i just hardcoded an array, and got the result `?categoryID[]=1&categoryID[]=2` and you suggest to do the same? Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @AlexanderKim I suggest categoryId: [1, 2].join(',')

Answer (score -1):

If you are here looking for how to achieve comma separated values like this:

`?size=4&sort=modifiedOn,name`

Do this:

```js
const http = axios.create({

  paramsSerializer: params => new URLSearchParams(params).toString()

})

http.get('/users', {
  params: {
    size: 4,
    sort: ['modifiedOn', 'name']
  }
})
```

Results in serialised query sting:

`?size=4&sort=modifiedOn%2Cname`