# Axios - How not to add [] to the multi parameters?

Tags: javascript, axios

Axios adds **square brackets** to the param if there are multiple params with an equal name. The problem is that I need not to include those brackets since I use `Django Rest Framework` and `Django Filters`.

How can I do that if I use this notation?

```
axios.get(list_url, {params: {somelist:[1,2,3]}})
```

I don't want `url/?somelist[]=1&somelist[]=2&somelist[]=3` 
Instead I want  `url/?somelist=1&somelist=2&somelist=3`

Answer (score 4):

Try to do it using paramsSerializer's `indexes:null` in axios config

```
axios.get(someurl, {
  params: {
    foo: [1, 2, 3]
  }, 
  paramsSerializer: { 
    indexes: null
  }
 });
```

I got this from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api

[screenshot with attributes of paramsSerializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7JVU.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this with `URLSearchParams` (a native object that exists in browsers and in Node.js as well):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { URLSearchParams } = require('url');

var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("q", 'test');
params.append("foo", 2);
params.append("foo", 11);
var request = {
  params: params
};
axios.get('http://google.com/', request).then(x => x.request).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [RequestConfig](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) object in axios documentation, there's a `paramsSerializer` function whose default value uses the `stringify` function of the [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) package in this way:

```js
// `paramsSerializer` is an optional function in charge of serializing `params`
// (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)
paramsSerializer: function (params) {
  return qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'brackets'})
},
```

If you want to keep the [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) package, you may use the `arrayFormat` option to specify the format of the output array:

```js
qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'indices' })
// 'a[0]=b&a[1]=c'
qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' })
// 'a[]=b&a[]=c'
qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' })
// 'a=b&a=c'
qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'comma' })
// 'a=b,c'
```

In your case :

```js
axios.get(listUrl, {
  params: {
    someList: [1, 2, 3]
  }, 
  paramsSerializer: (params) => qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'repeat'}),
});
```

Or at global instance level:

```js
const axios = axios.create({
  baseURL: someBaseUrl,
  paramsSerializer: (params) => qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'repeat'}),
});
```