# Is there a PHP equivalent to Java's ServletRequest.getParameterValues()?

Tags: php

I have an array of parameter values (with matching parameter names) in my request URL, like this:

> ?**my_array_of_values**=First&**my_array_of_values**=Second

In a Java servlet, I can detect them [like this](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)):

```
ServletRequest request = ...;
String[] myArrayOfValues = request.getParameterValues("my_array_of_values");
```

And this will result in:

> myArrayOfValues[0] = "First";
>
> myArrayOfValues[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)) = "Second";

...which is what I want.

However, I am not sure how to get the same results in PHP. For the same (above) parameters, when I try:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

it results in

> Array ( [my_array_of_values] => Second )

...i.e., the "First" parameter is lost.

I can see why this happens, but is there a way to detect such an array of parameter values in PHP as you can in Java/servlets? If not, is there a recommended workaround or alternative way of doing it?

Comment: If you use a framework like laravel this is possible. Or you have manually write a method. BTW what about $_GET ? this is also a key value array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the strange magic that happens in a Java environment, but query params must have different names or else they will overwrite each other.

In the example of `?my_array_of_values=First&my_array_of_values=Second` only the last given value is returned. It is the same as assigning different values to the same variable one after the other.

You may retrieve a single parameter as array though, by using angle brackets after the parameter name:

```
?my_array_of_values[]=First&my_array_of_values[]=Second
```

In that case `$_GET['my_array_of_values']` will be an array with all the given values.

See also: [Authoritative position of duplicate HTTP GET query keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746507/authoritative-position-of-duplicate-http-get-query-keys)

Comment: Is there a 'safe' way of accessing `$_GET['my_array_of_values']`? I have tried using `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'my_array_of_values')` (and `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'my_array_of_values[]')`) but no joy.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering You forgot to set the wanted filter – which is the third argument to `filter_input`: “If omitted, FILTER_DEFAULT will be used, which is equivalent to FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW. This will result in no filtering taking place by default.”; see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: Thanks. I see there is a `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` filter flag. Would this be safer when dealing with **$_POST** than using `array_filter()` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: I don't know about the broken way PHP processes parameters, but Java provides a simple way to transmit arrays of values: request.getParameterValues("my_array_of_values")