# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString does not allow to add duplicate key

Tags: c#, .net-core, query-string

I have Web API endpoint which expects a list of enum values. I am using HttpUtility.ParseQueryString to generate the query string where I want to pass multiple key-value pair in the query string as below,

```
../api/getdata?myEnum=One&myEnum=Two&myEnum=Three
```

But, the ParseQueryString is creating the query string url as below,

```
../api/getdata?myEnum=One%2cTwo%2cThree
```

Here is my code,

```
var queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
queryString.Add("myEnum", "One");
queryString.Add("myEnum", "Two");
queryString.Add("myEnum", "Three");
```

How can I create the expected query string url with duplicate keys.

```
../api/getdata?myEnum=One&myEnum=Two&myEnum=Three
```

Comment: ParseQueryString string returns a NameValueCollection which cannot have duplicate records per key, so the value will be "One,Two,Three". you can always write a custom method that will split the value and returns it the way you want. I'm not sure why you need to send the same parameters and can't just split the value on the other side (if you have access of course)

Comment: Unfortunately [there is no standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1746507/4137916) as to how to send multiple values, and .NET has largely settled on using `NameValueCollection` everywhere, meaning it almost necessarily uses the comma-separation method. You'd think it's an easy matter of then building the query string manually, so easy that there must be simple ways in the framework of doing so with proper encoding, but [you'd be mistaken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/829080/4137916).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the expected result via the `AddQueryString` method of the [`QueryHelpers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class in `ASP.NET Core`.

This class is contained in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` NuGet package.

```
string url = "http://yourservice/api/getdata";

url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, "myEnum", "One");
url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, "myEnum", "Two");
url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, "myEnum", "Three");

Console.WriteLine(url); // http://yourservice/api/getdata?myEnum=One&myEnum=Two&myEnum=Three
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been added a while back [0] using `QueryBuilder`.

You can now use query builder and pass in an `IEnumerable`. So if I wanted to add a bunch of `id=something` parameters to a query I can do this:

`var query = new QueryBuilder {{"id", itemIds}}.ToQueryString();`

This will give me a query string in the form: `?id=1&id=2&id=...`

In your particular case it would be something like this if you had an `IEnumerable` of your enums.

`var query = new QueryBuilder {{"myEnum", myEnums}}.ToQueryString();`

[0] https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7945