# Multiple values of a querystring parameter that contain commas C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.querystring

I have an issue in ASP.Net when trying to interrogate the query string for values when the parameter name is the same, and the values of that parameter contains commas.

For Instance, suppose I have a URL that reads as follows...

https://example.com/mypage.aspx?val=red%2cblue&val=black%2cwhite

As you can see, this URL has 2 querystring parameters both called "val", and the values for each have commas that have been URL encoded, but when I interrogate the query string parameter "val" in c#, I get an array of 4 separate items (red, blue, black and white) when what I actually need to get are the 2 values ("red,blue" and "black,white")

When reading the values in C# it seems the URL encoding is "helpfully" decoded, which in turn is causing me an issue in that I cant accurately define the values of my parameters. I'd normally read the querystring parameter, and perform a split on the comma, but this approach isnt working for me.

To complicate matters, I have no way of knowing how many commas can appear in my values, or how many values are being included. All the URLs below could be returned for example...

https://example.com/mypage.aspx

https://example.com/mypage.aspx?val=red%2cblue

https://example.com/mypage.aspx?val=red%2cblue&val=black%2cwhite&val=red%2cblue%2cgreen

https://example.com/mypage.aspx?val=red%2cblue&val=black%2cwhite&val=yellow

https://example.com/mypage.aspx?val=red%2cblue&val=black%2cwhite&val=red%2cblue%2cblack%2cwhite%2cgreen%2cyellow

Is there a simple way in C# to correctly interpret the query string values?

Comment: How do you read the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that having multiple keys with the same name in query string is not a [very good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746507/authoritative-position-of-duplicate-http-get-query-keys) due to absense of defined standard.

Though it seems that `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` can handle this scenario in a way that you need:

```
var nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("val=red%2cblue&val=black%2cwhite");
var result = nameValueCollection.GetValues("val");
foreach (var s in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s); // prints 2 strings: "red,blue" and "black,white"
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! Thanks.

Comment: @Karl was glad to help! Also usually `NameValueCollection` should already be available so you can try something like `Request.Params.GetValues("val")`.